# Changing dialog's parent disables drag and drop

Tags: c++, qt, drag-and-drop, qt5

I have a main window and a dialog that is opened from this window on a button click. For performance reasons, there is a dialog cache, that keeps an instance of the dialog and only shows it when the dialog should be opened instead of creating new instance. In the dialog, there's a `QListWidget` with some items which order can be changed by drag and drop. This works when I first open the dialog, but when I close it and open it again, I'm unable to drop the items, I get a `Qt::ForbiddenCursor`.

The issue seems to be caused by calling `setParent(nullptr)` when closing the dialog (or likely by just changing the parent). If I remove this line, drag and drop works. However I need this to prevent the dialog from being deleted by the parent and also the dialog can have different parents in different contexts (this isn't obvious from my simplified example). Any idea what is wrong with this approach? My Qt version is 5.9.3. Can this be a Qt bug?

MainWindow.h:

```
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "dialog.h"

#include <QPushButton>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <memory>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget* parent = nullptr) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);

        dialog.reset(new Dialog(this));
        dialog->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose, false);

        connect(ui->button, &QPushButton::pressed, [&]
        {
            dialog->setParent(this, dialog->windowFlags());
            dialog->open();
        });
    }

    ~MainWindow()
    {
        delete ui;
    }

private:
    Ui::MainWindow* ui;
    std::unique_ptr<Dialog> dialog;
};
```

Dialog.h:

```
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include <QDialog>

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget* parent) : QDialog(parent), ui(new Ui::Dialog)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);

        ui->listWidget->addItem("first");
        ui->listWidget->addItem("second");
        ui->listWidget->addItem("third");
    }

    ~Dialog()
    {
        delete ui;
    }

public slots:
    virtual void reject() override
    {
        setParent(nullptr);
        QDialog::reject();
    }

private:
    Ui::Dialog* ui;
};
```

Dialog.ui - simple dialog with QListWidget and reject button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>548</width>
    <height>397</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item>
    <widget class="QListWidget" name="listWidget">
     <property name="dragDropMode">
      <enum>QAbstractItemView::DragDrop</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="defaultDropAction">
      <enum>Qt::MoveAction</enum>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
   <item>
    <widget class="QDialogButtonBox" name="buttonBox">
     <property name="orientation">
      <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="standardButtons">
      <set>QDialogButtonBox::Close</set>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections>
  <connection>
   <sender>buttonBox</sender>
   <signal>accepted()</signal>
   <receiver>Dialog</receiver>
   <slot>accept()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>248</x>
     <y>254</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>157</x>
     <y>274</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
  <connection>
   <sender>buttonBox</sender>
   <signal>rejected()</signal>
   <receiver>Dialog</receiver>
   <slot>reject()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>316</x>
     <y>260</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>286</x>
     <y>274</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
 </connections>
</ui>
```

MainWindow.ui - default main window with one button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>432</width>
    <height>316</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="button">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>40</x>
      <y>30</y>
      <width>80</width>
      <height>21</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>PushButton</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>432</width>
     <height>20</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: @downvoter: I'm really interested what you think is wrong with this question...

Comment: One problem would be that the code can be <30 lines... your example is not minimal at all. Dumping the ui files that could be replaced with a couple of lines of C++ would be considered unkind, I guess. It’s awesome that there is some code to look at, but you could have had a complete example that compiles in less lines than the two UI files combined, probably. Minimization is a debugging technique, not merely a code presentation one. By minimizing you help yourself first. I imagine someone might have got a headache from the raw code dump — it can be a reflex reaction :)

Comment: @KubaOber: OK, I could do that and I considered it, but I just don't see how that helps. The problem is not in the ui files, it would just make the post a little shorter. But to me, it would be also less readable, as with Qt, you are used to the ui files, not C++ code that generates the gui... it would only add code with possible bugs, but with the ui, you know there is nothing funky going on... And if you want to reproduce it, you'll need an environment with Qt anyway, so it doesn't make a difference :)

Comment: "Used to UI files"? There's a reason that people came up with JSON: XML is not human-friendly. How can one argue that *more boilerplate* is somehow more readable? And who ever reads UI files? They are meant for `uic` and Qt Designer, not humans -- otherwise they'd be JSON, or YAML, or QML,  not XML. Never mind that you absolutely don't need so much boilerplate. Again: minimization. This isn't an enterprise app. It's a SO question. Less is more. And it does make a difference, because you're forcing anyone who answers to essentially copy-paste 5 separate files, for no reason at all.

Comment: @KubaOber: OK, now I get your point. I didn't know you can simply display a widget  without creating any kind of `QWindow` instance... That makes the mcve indeed much simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below reproduces the issue. It is indeed a Qt bug. OP reported the bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-70240

The problem is because `QWidget` recreates the drop site while the `Qt::Window` flag is off, invoking `QWindowsWindow::updateDropSite`, which does the wrong thing and calls `setDropSiteEnabled(false)`.

The two equivalent workarounds are:

1. `dialog->setParent(newParent)` is replaced by:

   ```
   auto flags = dialog->windowFlags();
   dialog->setParent(newParent, {});
   dialog->setWindowFlags(flags);
   ```
2. `dialog->setParent(nullptr)` is replaced by:

   ```
   dialog->setParent(nullptr, dialog->windowFlags());
   ```

The first workaround undoes the damaged state of the widget. The second workaround doesn't, i.e. needs to be always used, or else the first workaround has to be invoked once to restore the usable drop target state.

[image: screenshot]

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/dialog-parent-dnd-52061919
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   QApplication app(argc, argv);

   QWidget ui;
   QVBoxLayout layout{&ui};
   QPushButton button{"Toggle List"};
   QCheckBox workaround1{"Workaround 1"};
   QCheckBox workaround2{"Workaround 2"};
   for (auto w : QWidgetList{&button, &workaround1, &workaround2}) layout.addWidget(w);
   workaround2.setChecked(true);

   QListWidget listWidget;
   Q_ASSERT(!listWidget.testAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose));
   listWidget.setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
   listWidget.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView::DragDrop);
   listWidget.setDefaultDropAction(Qt::MoveAction);
   for (auto s : QStringList{"first", "second", "third"}) listWidget.addItem(s);

   QObject::connect(&button, &QPushButton::pressed, [&] {
      if (!listWidget.parent()) {
         if (!workaround1.isChecked())
            listWidget.setParent(&button, listWidget.windowFlags());
         else {
            auto flags = listWidget.windowFlags();
            listWidget.setParent(&button, {});
            listWidget.setWindowFlags(flags);
         }
         listWidget.show();
      } else {
         if (!workaround2.isChecked())
            listWidget.setParent(nullptr);
         else
            listWidget.setParent(nullptr, listWidget.windowFlags());
         listWidget.close();
      }
   });

   ui.setMinimumSize(320, 200);
   ui.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```